# How to pass a form with an array of images to php using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

PFB my Html code :

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>File One</label>
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file[]">
<br/>
<label>File Two</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file[]">
<br/>
<label>File Three</label>
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file[]">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am trying to submit this form using ajax as below :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(function() {
 $('#form').submit(function(event) {
 var name = $("#name").val();
 var file[] = $("#file[]").val();

 var dataString = 'name='+name+'&file[]='+file[];


 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "k.php",
 data: dataString,
 success: function(data123){
 alert(data123);
 }
 });

 return false;
 });
 });
</script>
```

But its not working. i:e the below line :

```
 var file[] = $("#file[]").val();

 var dataString = 'name='+name+'&file[]='+file[];
```

Any help would be highly useful.

I need to submit multiple photos along with text fields using ajax function but I am stuck in this issue from the past many days.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading files using ajax, you need to do some extra work using the FormData object.

Check out http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax for an example of how to do this.